# bash doesn't show current working directory on screen

Tags: macos, bash, gnu-screen

When using iTerm2 on my OS X, the bash prompt shows my current working directory normally:

```
mbp:tp0 renato$
```

But when I use screen, the bash prompt changes to:

```
bash-3.2$
```

How I make the bash prompt when using screen to be the same as the normal prompt? And maybe show which screen it is to differentiate from the normal prompt, that would be helpful.

Comment: I just noticed that my vim configuration also changes when using screen, why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely your environment variables are changing when using screen. To prevent screen changing your environment, check your .screenrc. Use something like:

```
shell -$SHELL
```

for the shell.

Using something like `shell /bin/bash` would reset your environment. 
Instead use `shell -/bin/bash` in that case.

For the prompt:
you need to set up your PS1 variable like this:

```
export PS1="\\u@\h \\W]\\$"
```

This would get you a bash prompt with the [username@host working directory]$ format.

For a useful explanation go to:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Comment: Ok, you solved my doubt about the prompt, but vim's configuration is different when using screen (the syntax highlighting uses different colors). Why is that?

Comment: Do you have a HOME value when using screen? (`echo $HOME`) vim should try to get the configuration from there (vimrc I believe)

Comment: Yes, the value is Users/renato, the same value when outside gnu screen.

Comment: Inside screen, what kind of TERM are you emulating? `echo TERM` If it has less than 256 colors it would cause vim to not use highlighting.

Comment: when using `echo $TERM` the output inside screen is just `screen`, while in the normal terminal it is `xterm`. How do I change the TERM to `xterm` then?

Comment: I changed the TERM by appending `term xterm` in ~/.screenrc, but the syntax highlighting colors are all different too (there is syntax highlighting, but the colors are all weird)